# PHP: Коды Грея и задачи перебора

Tags: php, алгоритм

Ребята помогите решить следующую задачу:

Надо было написать алгоритм перебора **[Кода Грея](https://habrahabr.ru/post/200806/): **

Но поскольку небыло времени вспоминать как работают с двоичными системами и.т.д,
то написал по логике которая походу много памяти сожрала и тест не прошел. Но очень хочется решить его на PHP.

```
function collect($n = 3){
    $result = ["0", "1"];

    for($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $default = $result;
        $count = count($result);

        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $result[] = "0{$default[$j]}";
        }

        for($k = $count - 1; $k >= 0; $k--) {
            $result[] = "1{$result[$k]}";
        }
    }

    $result = array_unique($result);
    $output = array_slice($result, -$n);

    return implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
}

var_dump(collect());
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря подсмотрел ответ на java , и перебрал его на PHP. :)

```
function  Gray2($n){
    for($k= 1<<$n; --$k>=0;)
    {
        $s=$k^($k>>1);
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) printf("%d",($s>>$i)&1);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
echo Gray2(2);
```